# Count number of times a value occurs and get the sum in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have seen these questions have been answered multiple times before. However, my case is very unique and I need your input.

I've a data that looks like this

```
PipeID     price
125        100
125        200
456        300
523        400
523        500
```

I got the number of occurrence by PipeID using the following code

```
num_occur <- df %>%
   group_by(PipeID) %>%
   summarise(PipeID = sum(PipeID), freq = n())
```

This gives me the following results

```
PipeID    freq
125       2
456       1
523       2
```

However I want to find the sum of the frequency. For example, the sum of the number of times a frequency of 2 occurs. The desired output is as follows:

```
freq   count
2      4
1      1
```

Any timely help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's actually not that different from what you've already done: if you can count frequencies of IDs, you can count frequencies of frequencies. All you're changing is what you group by

Answer (score 2):

You simplify a bit with

```r
df %>%
  count(PipeID, name = "freq") %>%
  group_by(freq) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(freq))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>    freq count
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     4
```

Comment: Or slightly shorter: `df %>% count(PipeID, name = "freq") %>% count(freq, name = "count", wt = freq)`

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "PipeID     price
125        100
125        200
456        300
523        400
523        500",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(PipeID) %>%
  summarise(PipeID = sum(PipeID),
            freq = n()) %>%
  group_by(freq) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(freq))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>    freq count
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>